# Is this an array in crescent order

Tags: c

this is a very simple question.

I would just like to know if this is an array in crescent order :

a = [5,5,5,5,5]

Because for me it'd be constant and not crescent.

Thank you!

Comment: This is not about C.

Comment: It is crescent/increasing, but not *strictly* crescent. A strict inequality means `x < y`, if it is not strict it can mean `x <= y` depending on the terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence that is strictly increasing/decreasing upto a point and then strictly decreasing/increasing is what I would expect to be called as crescent order.

E.g. `[1 2 3 2 1]` or `[9 8 7 6 10 12 15]`.

So no,  `[5,5,5,5,5]` is not in crescent order.